# Authentication Failed on SourceTree while cloning BitBucket project

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server, sourcetree

I am trying to clone a project from my bitbucket to my computer, using SourceTree.

I tried to do so from the web interface :

[image]

But it always failed.

Here is the details of the error.

[image]

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** As mentioned below an update (1.6.25) has been released which fixes this error.

**Original:** Authentication in Version 1.6.24 of SourceTree is currently not working well. Use version 1.6.23 instead. You can find it here: http://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/SourceTreeSetup_1.6.23.exe

Enjoy:)

Comment: Another thread related to this issue can be found here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/164023/password-not-working-on-sourcetree

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem is now solved (Installation of the 1.6.23 version)

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, the problem is with Askpass.exe
>
> We recently changed the logging framework we used to slf4net/log4net and this, unexpectedly is being picked up by askpass.exe.
>   But unfortunately since askpass.exe has no configuration in place it logs some output to stdout by default, this is interfering with the expected stdout output from askpass.exe.
>
> We will release a 1.6.25 tomorrow with a proper fix.
>
> **Work Around**
>
> As a temporary workaround copying the attached [Askpass.exe.config](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/attachment/183776/183776_Askpass.exe.config) file in to
>
> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree`
>
> will provide the necessary configuration and should fix the multiple authentication requests.
>
> You may find that unfortunately SourceTree has deleted what it thought were 'failing' passwords. Apologies for this you will need to re-enter them.

You can see the issue on Atlassian's own Jira: [SRCTREEWIN-3944](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-3944)

**Edit:** Said update appears to be available now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Help > Check for Updates > Update
```

Worked for me

Answer (score -1):

It is because of the update which is the Two-step verification. I suggest you read [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/two-step-verification-777023203.html) first to read more about their update and then you proceed over [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html). I was able to change my default HTTPS protocol to SSH protocol by following the steps above.